# перекодировка русских символов при отсылке на сайт

Tags: java, utf-8, text, cp1251

Если в подобном запросе к сайту передаются русские символы, то на сайте они появляются в виде знаков вопроса.

для передачи русских символов мне нужно составлять таблицу соответсвий для перекодировки, или есть более изящное решение?

```js
try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).build()) {
 URI u = new URIBuilder()
  .setScheme(SCHEME)
  .build();
 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(u);

 List < NameValuePair > nvps = new ArrayList < > ();
 nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subject", "какаф нибудь фраза"));
}
```

сам сайт кодирует исмволы так %C0%C2% итд

> Аа-C0|E0, Бб-C1|E1, Вв-C2|E2, Гг-C3|E3, Дд-C4|E4, Ее-C5|E5, Ёё-A8|B8, Жж-C6|E6, Зз-C7|E7, Ии-C8|E8, Йй-C9|E9, Кк-CA|EA, Лл-CB|EB, Мм-CC|EC, Нн-CD|ED, Оо-CE|EE, Пп-CF|EF, Рр-D0|F0, Сс-D1|F1, Тт-D2|F2, Уу-D3|F3, Фф-D4|F4… Хх-D5|F5, Цц-D6|F6, Чч-D7|F7, Шш-D8|F8, Щщ-D9|F9, Ъъ-DA|FA, Ыы-DB|FB, Ьь-DC|FC, Ээ-DD|FD, Юю-DE|FE, Яя-DF|FF

Comment: вы хотите заPOSTить данные как `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? Убедитесь, что `"\u0444\u0440\u0430\u0437\u0430"` и `"фраза"` одинаковы в вашем случае (исходный код `.java` в ожидаемой кодировке сохранён). В общем случае [тяжело определить формально, какую кодировку ожидает сервер](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm). Я не знаком с особенностями Java http-клиента, но возможно его поведение по умолчанию уже достаточно.  Если нет, то желаемую кодировку явно подставьте:  `httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));`

Comment: Обратите внимание, что кодировка исходного кода не имеет никакого отношения к кодировке ожидаемой сервером.